# Limit a FreeForm based on a maximum number of allowed entries?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm trying to create a form that will only allow a maximum of 40 users to complete. After the form hits 40 entries, I would like to hide the fields and show a message (ie. "This course has reached it's capacity and is now closed")

I've tried using FreeForms total_results in an {If} statement, but I can't seem to get it working.

Any Thoughts? Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
{exp:freeform:entries 
                    form_name="camp_registration"
                }

                    {if freeform:no_results}
                        {exp:freeform:form
                            form_name="camp_registration"
                            required="first_name|last_name|date_of_birth|email"
                            }
                            test
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>{freeform:label:email} {if freeform:error:email}<span class="error"> - Required</span>{/if}</label><br />
                                {freeform:field:email attr:class="form-control"}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        {/exp:freeform:form}
                    {/if}


                    {if freeform:count == 1}

                        {if freeform:total_results < 40} /* I'm pretty sure this is where there's a problem */

                            {exp:freeform:form
                                form_name="camp_registration"
                                required="first_name|last_name|date_of_birth|email"
                             }

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>{freeform:label:email} {if freeform:error:email}<span class="error"> - Required</span>{/if}</label><br />
                                    {freeform:field:email attr:class="form-control"}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                                </div>

                            {/exp:freeform:form}

                        {/if}

                        {if freeform:total_results >= 40}
                            <p>Sorry, maximum form entries allowed reached.</p>
                        {/if}

                    {/if}

                {/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Comment: Have you tried the query module to perform a count of entries in that form? Looking at the Freeform docs it doesn't appear that free:total_results is a valid variable

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `{exp:freeform:form}` with an `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag pair and use conditionals to determine if there are more than less than 40 entries for the form. If there are less, present the form, if not, show a message:

```
{exp:freeform:entries /* your other parameters */}

  {if freeform:no_results}
     {exp:freeform:form /* your other parameters */}
        // Your form code. This will show up if there are no form entries yet.
     {/exp:freeform:form}
  {/if}

  {if freeform:count == 1}

    {if freeform:total_results < 40}
       {exp:freeform:form /* your other parameters */}
          // Your form code
       {/exp:freeform:form}
    {/if}

    {if freeform:total_results >= 40}
       <p>Sorry, maximum form entries allowed reached.</p>
    {/if}

  {/if}

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

The `{if freeform:count == 1}` conditional is to prevent the `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag from looping and displaying the same content multiple times.

Comment: This is a better solution than the one I posted.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work. I can't get anything but a blank page. I think it's breaking when it hits freeform:total_results. I've updated the code in my original post. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try wrapping your freeform:total_results and freeform:count variables with quotes and brackets, since they are in a conditional, i.e. `{if '{freeform:count}' == 1}` and `{if '{freeform:total_results}' < 40}` and `{if '{freeform:total_results}' >= 40}`

Answer (score 2):

What I would try is move your form to an embedded template and in your main template put the following code which is using freeform:entries rather than freeform:form -

```
{exp:freeform:entries
    form_name="camp_registration"
    limit="100" 
    } 

    {embed="template_group/_formname" form_count="{freeform:total_results}"}

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Then in your embedded template where you have the conditional you can do a check on the value with {embed:form_count}

Comment: Actually, to save you from a performance hit, you wouldn't need an embed to have {exp:freeform:form} within {exp:freeform:entries}. I'll post a full example in another response.