# Can't Limit Freeform Entries Above 50

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm trying to make use of code much like the solution provided to this user ([Limit a FreeForm based on a maximum number of allowed entries?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/limit-a-freeform-based-on-a-maximum-number-of-allowed-entries)) to hide the form after a certain number of entries is reached.

The issue I've found is that the conditionals work up to 50, but not beyond that point... and I'd like to hide the form automatically when 200 entries are reached.

Does anyone know how to do this? This is the code I'm using:

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_name="conference_2017"}
{if '{freeform:count}' == 1}
{if '{freeform:total_results}' < 200}
<p>All fields below are required. Thank you!</p>
{exp:freeform:form form_name="conference_2017" required="full_name|title|organization|email|phone|mailing_address|postal_code" form:id="contact_form" form:class="contact_form" return="conference/registered" secure_action="yes"}
<! -- Form Content -->
{/exp:freeform:form}
{/if}
{if '{freeform:total_results}' >= 200}<p>Due to exceptionally strong interest we’ve reached our registration limit. If you have any questions or would like to enquire about the possibility of attending, please contact XXXXX at {encode="XXXXX" title="XXXXX"}.</p>{/if}{/if}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

I'm using Freeform Pro 4.2.5 on EE 2.11.7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the default limit for `{exp:freeform:entries}` template tag is `50`. So you'll just need to specify the `limit` parameter with a value of `200`. :)

`{exp:freeform:entries
   form_name="conference_2017"
   limit="200"
}`

Comment: Ah-ha! That makes total sense—and it now works perfectly. Thank you!